# Where to call "Vue.use(plugin)" when using SSR in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, vue-ssr

I have a plugin (bootstrap-vue) that I want to initialize with `Vue.use()`. Right now, I use it in the client entry (inside `router.onReady()`), but I get the following warning:

> The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside `<p>`, or missing `<tbody>`. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.

I use server-side-rendering (SSR) and am not sure where to call the plugin initialization properly. Thanks!

Comment: trying to put `Vue.use(yourPlugin)` next to the entry point of your app.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it already! A detailed answer for others having this question follows.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Sphinx for the hint! The answer is to put it into the client (!) entry point of the Vue app, e.g. where `new Vue()` is called:

```js
// Create the main Vue app
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
})

// Register plugins
Vue.use(YourPlugin)
```

It will work properly with other SSR components of the Vue app.